# Overlapping confidence interval with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I'd like to plot two confidence intervals with geom_ribbon in `PSO` and `PSOA`. My dataset is given by

```
id   Meta prob       mean    lowerci   upperci
1   PSO  0.1 6705423.00   9913.939  151671.3
2   PSO  0.2 6705423.00  24352.031  393418.7
3   PSO  0.3 6705423.00  64719.335  444035.0
4   PSO  0.4 6705423.00  85058.168  600026.5
5   PSO  0.5 6705423.00 140437.916  756819.1
6   PSO  0.6 6705423.00 179236.196  952494.7
7   PSO  0.7 6705423.00 211278.350  773605.9
8   PSO  0.8 6705423.00 169915.851 1078624.1
9   PSO  0.9 6705423.00 263216.389  936007.2
10  PSO  1.0 6705423.00 266200.032 1061063.0
11 PSOA  0.1   52460.43   9913.939  151671.3
12 PSOA  0.2  202813.18  24352.031  393418.7
13 PSOA  0.3  252836.56  64719.335  444035.0
14 PSOA  0.4  329661.97  85058.168  600026.5
15 PSOA  0.5  450833.52 140437.916  756819.1
16 PSOA  0.6  424932.84 179236.196  952494.7
17 PSOA  0.7  486794.40 211278.350  773605.9
18 PSOA  0.8  634493.58 169915.851 1078624.1
19 PSOA  0.9  521509.18 263216.389  936007.2
20 PSOA  1.0  648183.78 266200.032 1061063.0
```

I tried to use the code above, but I could not plot the `geom_ribbon` in PSO ("HERE" in figure).

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat2, aes(x=prob, y=mean, colour=Meta)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=dat2$lowerci, ymax=dat2$upperci), linetype=2, alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: You can't plot the ribbon there because the y-values of the ribbon are identical to the `PSOA` group. Thus, it looks like you aren't plotting the `PSO` group but it is being plotted. It just is being covered by the `PSOA` group

Comment: Do you actually want to plot something like `ymax = mean + upperci` and `ymin = mean - lowerci`?

Comment: The mean of `PSO` is equal, but the limits of confidence intervals are different. In addition, I'd like `ymax = upperci`, `ymax = mean + upperci` is very greater  `ymax = upperci`.

Comment: Yes the limits differ within the `PSO` group. However, the `upperci` and `lowerci` are identical across the `PSO` and `PSOA` group causing `PSO` to be covered up

Comment: Ok, but your `CIs` dont really make sense for the `PSO` group because the mean is not even close to contained within them

Comment: Yes man, the `upperci` and `lowerci` are wrong, in correct datasets they are different. This solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the data for `lowerci` and `upperci` is exactly the same for the `PSO` and `PSOA` groups. When plotted, the `PSOA` group is "covering up" the `PSO` group giving the appearance it is not being plotted. To see how this is working you can run the same code with just a subset of your data:

```
ggplot(data=dat2[dat2$Meta == "PSO",], aes(x=prob, y=mean, colour=Meta)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lowerci, ymax=upperci), linetype=2, alpha=0.1)
```

Note how the ribbon for `PSO` looks identical to your original plot?

[image]

Comment: Ah yep, you were right, didn't look at the actual numbers.  Will delete my answer